# Does Google Maps follow W3C guidelines for accessibility

Tags: google-maps, accessibility

Does google maps conform with the w3c accessibility recommendations(A,AA,AAA)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test by yourself using some online validators :

- a complete list of accessibility validators by the w3c : http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/complete.html
- a Gmaps accessibility check result http://wave.webaim.org/report?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2Fmaps%2FIEXW&js=2 (result)

I guess some improvements could be done, but by nature rendering and displaying map has some limitations regarding accessibility.

Answer (score 4):

Judging from [this link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=0b8241662c7fe136&hl=en) the answer is NO.

Also check out [this accessibility test](http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/gp3g10/Accessibility.htm).

But then again, I guess you'd get a more trustworthy and formal answer by contacting the Google Maps team.

Comment: +1 for the second link.The first link is just the first result from a google search.

Comment: Not that I mind, as the first link is indeed a first result from a google search, but it is not "just", it is an answer to your exact question in a organic google maps forum, given by a known Top Contributor (It's most relevent as far as answers go). Oh, and and the second link is the fifth-six on that same google search.

Comment: It is a common practice to make a search first and then ask something in a forum.As a matter of fact i took the title from that particular question and paste it as the title of my question.Personally when i give an answer i prefer to already know the answer or part of it and not searching.Also i ask the question here because there are enthusiasts and proffesionals in gis and not just good searchers.Don't take this personally.Thank you

Comment: @Argir If you're looking for a particular kind of answer and have already done a search, then it is incumbent on you to let us know that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The embedded Google maps are not accessible to sighted keyboard-only users, nor to non-visual screen reader users (particularly this second group). The actual Google Maps site maps are more accessible. Your best bet is to provide street addresses and zip codes in text to allow Google Map search. You could also create links to the specific search on Google Maps in a span or div and hide them visually with CSS clipping.

Simply running an automated accessibility testing tool won't provide you with the full picture, since only a subset of the WCAG success criteria can be tested with automated tools.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference check here:
http://dev-tracker.measuremap.com/accessibility/

Comment: now dead link and so we will never know what it lined to